# Complex cell formula evaluation does not work using apache-poi

Tags: excel, excel-formula, apache-poi

I am using apache-poi api (v3.9) in my project to process the excel template. I do update the all required cell values in all sheets of my excel document. I am using some complex formulas to calculate the double value for some cell. 
I am facing the problem in reading the cell value of a cell having some complex formula. This complex formula works fine in excel sheet but return zero when I read it using poi.

Complex formula which I am using:

```
"=SUMPRODUCT(--('A-La-Carte'!$L$12:$L$100000=E129)*IF('A-La-Carte'!$K$12:$K$100000<>"-",'A-La-Carte'!$K$12:$K$100000,0)*IF(ISNUMBER(INT(LEFT('A-La-Carte'!$D$12:$D$100000,2))),12/INT(LEFT('A-La-Carte'!$D$12:$D$100000,2)),0))+(NOW()*0)"
```

If I change the above formula with some simple formula it works fine.

Below is the sample code which I used to read the cell value:

```
XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(workbook);
private String getCellValue(String cellRef,
        XSSFWorkbook workbook,String sheetName) {

    XSSFSheet xssfSheet = workbook.getSheet(sheetName);
    CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cellRef);
    XSSFRow r = xssfSheet.getRow(cellReference.getRow());
     if (r != null) {
        XSSFCell c = r.getCell(cellReference.getCol());

           if(c.getCellType()==XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            return c.getNumericCellValue()+"";
           else if((c.getCellType()==XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA)){
               return c. getNumericCellValue()+"";
           }
           return c.getStringCellValue();



     }
     return null;
}
```

Can anybody tell me whats wrong with formula or API?

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache POI? And what happens when you upgrade to a more recent one?

Comment: @Gagravarr: Even its not working with latest version of POI.